# Does the Stormbreaker follow the same worthy rules as Mjolnir

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, there was a moment when Thor summons the Stormbreaker and Thanos catches it in between and uses it to beat Thor.

Just thinking if anyone can pick up Stormbreaker or if it is the same as with Mjolnir.

Comment: I would have been nice to see Thor go back in time to ask his dad to cast a spell on it for him.